# Static casting between types for Generic nested records

Tags: casting, f#, static, type-conversion, lazy-evaluation

Nested F# Record with generic type parameter, how do I statically cast between types in nested structure equivalent to traversing and performing `'T |> 'K`, e.g. `float |> int`?

Currently I am Naively traversing the nested records and explicitly converting the type with `from:float |> to:int` or equivalently `int(from)`. However, this is not very beautiful.

```
type Person<'T> = {Id : int; Value : 'T}
type Family<'T> = {Id : 'T; People : seq<Person<'T>>}

let fam1 = {Id = 1.0; People = [{Id = 1.1; Value = 2.9}; {Id = 1.2; Value = 4.4}]} : Family<float>
let fam2 = {Id = 2.0; People = [{Id = 2.1; Value = 3.9}; {Id = 2.2; Value = 5.4}]} : Family<float>

let partyFloat = seq{ yield fam1; yield fam2}

// In general, how to do this from a type T to a type K where conversion using T |> K will work
let partyInt : seq<Family<int>> = partyFloat
```

How to statically and/or 
    lazily convert to `seq<Family<int>>`?
In my real world case I have a DiffSharp `D` type that can be converted to a float with `D |> float` or `float(D)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic way to cast the insides of types, you have to write your own.

It is idiomatic for F# and functional programming in general (and I personally recommend it, too) to write small functions for simple data transformations, and then assemble them together:

```
let mapPerson f p = { Id = p.Id; Value = f p.Value }
let mapFamily f fm = { Id = f fm.Id; People = Seq.map (mapPerson f) fm.People }
let mapParty f = Seq.map (mapFamily f)

let partyInt = mapParty int partyFloat
```

But of course you can do it in one big messy go:

```
let partyInt = 
    partyFloat
    |> Seq.map (fun fm -> 
        { Id = int fm.Id
          People = 
             fm.People
             |> Seq.map (fun p ->
                 { Id = p.Id; Value = int p.Value }
             )
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you recommend for or against putting your first set of functions inside the type as static or non-static members? For instance these two will work:
**(1)** `let t1 = people |> Seq.map (Person<Foo>.Convert1 int)`,
but ugly with the <Foo> that is ignored.
**(2)** `let t2 = people |> Seq.map (fun p -> p.Convert2 int)`.

**(3)** I suppose it is not possible to be able to make this work `Seq.map(Person<int>.Convert)`?

Comment: Don't use static members. Put that function into a module named `Person`. Also, idiomatic name for such function is `map`, not `Convert`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are asking for are covariance ie that this should compile

```
let vs : obj list = ["1"; "2"]
```

F# doesn't support covariance (or contravariance) and probably never will. C# does however so you could write something like this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

interface IPerson<out T>
{
  int Id { get; }
  T Value { get; }
}

interface IFamily<out T>
{
  int Id { get; }
  IEnumerable<IPerson<T>> Members { get; }
}

static class Program
{
  static IFamily<string> CreateFamily()
  {
    return null;
  }
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    IFamily<string> familyOfString = CreateFamily();
    IFamily<object> familyOfObject = familyOfString;
  }
}
```

However, there's a functional pattern that could help us called polymorphic lenses.

[image: Learning curve of popular haskell concepts]
(Picture from reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2qjnho/learning_curves_for_different_programming/)

I used to think that polymorphic lenses isn't possible in F# due to the lack of higher-rank types. However, there's a hidden gem out there: http://www.fssnip.net/7Pk

Vesa Karvonen (IIRC he is also behind hopac so he's pretty cool) implements polymorphic lenses in F# using some pretty interesting tricks.

We can then map the inner values of an immutable structure reasonably easy.

```
let input : Family<int> = 
  {
    Id      = 1
    Members = [{ Id = 10; Value = 123}; { Id = 11; Value = 456}]
  }
printfn "%A" input

let output : Family<string> =
  input
  |> over Family.membersL (overAll Person.valueL ((+) 1 >> string))
printfn "%A" output
```

Full source code

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The code below taken from: http://www.fssnip.net/7Pk
//  by Vesa+Karvonen - http://www.fssnip.net/authors/Vesa+Karvonen
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

type LensFunctor<'a> =
  | Over of 'a
  | View
  member t.map a2b =
    match t with
     | Over a -> Over (a2b a)
     | View -> View

type Lens<'s,'t,'a,'b> = ('a -> LensFunctor<'b>) -> 's -> LensFunctor<'t>

module Lens =
  let view l s =
    let r = ref Unchecked.defaultof<_>
    s |> l (fun a -> r := a; View) |> ignore
    !r

  let over l f =
    l (f >> Over) >> function Over t -> t | _ -> failwith "Impossible"
  let set l b = over l <| fun _ -> b
  let (>->) a b = a << b

  let lens get set = fun f s ->
    (get s |> f : LensFunctor<_>).map (fun f -> set f s)

  let fstL f = lens fst (fun x (_, y) -> (x, y)) f
  let sndL f = lens snd (fun y (x, _) -> (x, y)) f

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The code above taken from: http://www.fssnip.net/7Pk
//  by Vesa+Karvonen - http://www.fssnip.net/authors/Vesa+Karvonen
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  let overAll l f = List.map (over l f)

open Lens

type Person<'T> = { Id : int; Value : 'T }

module Person =
  let idS    i p          = { p with Id = i     }
  let valueS v { Id = i } = { Id = i; Value = v }

  let idL    f = lens (fun {Id    = i } -> i) idS    f
  let valueL f = lens (fun {Value = v } -> v) valueS f

type Family<'T> = { Id : int; Members : Person<'T> list }

module Family =
  let idS      i f          = { f with Id = i     }
  let membersS m { Id = i } = { Id = i; Members = m }

  let idL      f = lens (fun {Id      = i } -> i) idS      f
  let membersL f = lens (fun {Members = m } -> m) membersS f


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let input = 
    {
      Id      = 1
      Members = [{ Id = 10; Value = 123}; { Id = 11; Value = 456}]
    }
  printfn "%A" input

  let output =
    input
    |> over Family.membersL (overAll Person.valueL ((+) 1 >> string))
  printfn "%A" output

  0
```